TypeError: 'numpy.bool_' object is not iterable when working with SetFit and Optuna
I am trying to train a few shot text classifier using SetFit and Optuna. When I run my code, I get the error TypeError: 'numpy.bool_' object is not iterable. I don't understand where the error comes from, as I am not using numpy at all.
Here's my code, the full traceback can be found below:
transformer_model = 'sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2' 

def make_model(params = None):
    multi_target_strategy = params['multi_target_strategy'] if params else 'one-vs-rest'
    return SetFitModel.from_pretrained(transformer_model, multi_target_strategy = multi_target_strategy)

args = TrainingArguments(
    loss = CosineSimilarityLoss,
    batch_size=32,
    num_epochs=2,
    num_iterations = 5,
    end_to_end=True
)

model_training = Trainer( # issues with Trainer 
    model_init = make_model,
    args = args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
    metric='accuracy',
    #sampling_strategy = 'undersampling', 
    column_mapping={'text': 'text', 'label': 'label'}
)

def hyperparameter_search_space(trial: Trial):
    learning_rate = trial.suggest_float('learning_rate', 1e-5, 1e-3, log=True)
    batch_size = trial.suggest_int('batch_size', 4, 32)
    multi_target_strategy = trial.suggest_categorical('multi_target_strategy', ['one-vs-rest', 'classifier-chain']) #'multi_output',

    print(f"Hyperparameters: learning_rate={learning_rate}, batch_size={batch_size}, multi_target_strategy={multi_target_strategy}")
    
    return {
        'learning_rate': learning_rate,
        'batch_size': batch_size,
        'multi_target_strategy': multi_target_strategy
    }

optimised_model = model_training.hyperparameter_search(hyperparameter_search_space, n_trials= 3)`

And here the full error traceback:
Trial 0 failed with parameters: {'learning_rate': 9.041915119772932e-05, 'batch_size': 11, 'multi_target_strategy': 'one-vs-rest'} because of the following error: TypeError("'numpy.bool_' object is not iterable").
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/[myname]/DeepLearningVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/optuna/study/_optimize.py", line 196, in _run_trial
    value_or_values = func(trial)
  File "/Users/[myname]/DeepLearningVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setfit/integrations.py", line 27, in _objective
    trainer.train(trial=trial)
  File "/Users/[myname]/DeepLearningVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setfit/trainer.py", line 410, in train
    self.train_embeddings(*full_parameters, args=args)
  File "/Users/[myname]/DeepLearningVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setfit/trainer.py", line 443, in train_embeddings
    train_dataloader, loss_func, batch_size, num_unique_pairs = self.get_dataloader(
  File "/Users/[myname]/DeepLearningVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setfit/trainer.py", line 502, in get_dataloader
    data_sampler = ContrastiveDataset(
  File "/Users/[myname]/DeepLearningVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setfit/sampler.py", line 66, in __init__
    self.generate_multilabel_pairs()
  File "/Users/[myname]/DeepLearningVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setfit/sampler.py", line 100, in generate_multilabel_pairs
    if any(np.logical_and(_label, label)):
TypeError: 'numpy.bool_' object is not iterable
[W 2024-06-05 14:10:04,814] Trial 0 failed with value None.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/[myname]/DeepLearningVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setfit/trainer.py", line 932, in hyperparameter_search
    best_run = backend_dict[backend](self, n_trials, direction, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/[myname]/DeepLearningVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setfit/integrations.py", line 37, in run_hp_search_optuna
    study.optimize(_objective, n_trials=n_trials, timeout=timeout, n_jobs=n_jobs)
  File "/Users/[myname]/DeepLearningVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/optuna/study/study.py", line 451, in optimize
    _optimize(
  File "/Users/[myname]/DeepLearningVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/optuna/study/_optimize.py", line 62, in _optimize
    _optimize_sequential(
  File "/Users/[myname]/DeepLearningVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/optuna/study/_optimize.py", line 159, in _optimize_sequential
    frozen_trial = _run_trial(study, func, catch)
  File "/Users/[myname]/DeepLearningVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/optuna/study/_optimize.py", line 247, in _run_trial
    raise func_err
  File "/Users/[myname]/DeepLearningVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/optuna/study/_optimize.py", line 196, in _run_trial
    value_or_values = func(trial)
  File "/Users/[myname]/DeepLearningVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setfit/integrations.py", line 27, in _objective
    trainer.train(trial=trial)
  File "/Users/[myname]/DeepLearningVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setfit/trainer.py", line 410, in train
    self.train_embeddings(*full_parameters, args=args)
  File "/Users/[myname]/DeepLearningVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setfit/trainer.py", line 443, in train_embeddings
    train_dataloader, loss_func, batch_size, num_unique_pairs = self.get_dataloader(
  File "/Users/[myname]/DeepLearningVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setfit/trainer.py", line 502, in get_dataloader
    data_sampler = ContrastiveDataset(
  File "/Users/[myname]/DeepLearningVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setfit/sampler.py", line 66, in __init__
    self.generate_multilabel_pairs()
  File "/Users/[myname]/DeepLearningVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setfit/sampler.py", line 100, in generate_multilabel_pairs
    if any(np.logical_and(_label, label)):
TypeError: 'numpy.bool_' object is not iterable
´´´

